# Where do I create helpers in Yii?

Tags: php, yii2

I want to create an EBay API wrapper object. In Rails, I would create a helper so it would be available in the controller and view. Where do I create such an object in Yii? There is no helpers/ directory. This was the closest concept I could find: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-application-components.html

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a `helpers` directory if you want, there is nothing to stop you, just create your namespace accordingly. I personally put them in the `components` directory.

You are using namespaces now :) enjoy it. If you are using the advance app then there is already defined a namespace for the backend for example that is called..... backend. What does this mean it means that when you `use` a class that is found in a known namespace it starts from there and it tries to guess the path to your class.

For example:

```
use backend/helpers/foo/Bar;
```

Bar should be found in the backend/helpers/foo directory. Yii2 will know where to find it because it knows where `backend` is.

Comment: There is no components directory. I'm using the new Yii. Just because I create the helpers/ directory, doesn't mean it will load the class. I seriously doubt it is scanning the entire file system and automatically including every PHP file it finds on every request. Where do I specify the autoloading? Can you give an example?

Comment: this is yii2, why do you need autoloading? just put it in the correct namespace app/helpers/nameoffile or common/helpers/nameoffile then in the file you need to put use then just use it.

Comment: Ok I tried creating a function in a file in `helpers/` with `namespace app\helpers;`. The view has `use app\helpers;` and `<?= app\helpers\isGrid() ?>` but it still complains `Call to undefined function app\helpers\isGrid()`.

Comment: Even in the PHP example, it shows you have to `include()` the file. http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php How would Yii know to `include()` that file? `use` is just a PHP keyword and doesn't execute any code.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work with the following, but I think there is a better answer.

`helpers/myhelpers.php`

```
<?php
namespace app\helpers;

function isGrid() {
  return true;
}
?>
```

`views/shopping/index.php`

```
<?php
use app\helpers; // this doesn't seem to work - how does Yii know to include the files?
include('../helpers/myhelpers.php');
...
<?= app\helpers\isGrid() ?>
```

For some reason, you have to still give the full namespace path to the function. It won't work without it.